# Why does my GtkTreeView sort func receive a row with None in it?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

I've set up a `gtk.TreeView` with a `gtk.TreeStore`. One column contains formatted dollar amounts, and I've set up sorting by that column as follows:

```
    def sortmon(model, i1, i2):
        v1 = model[i1][COL_MONEY]
        v2 = model[i2][COL_MONEY]
        return cmp(float(v1.replace("$","").replace(",","")),
                   float(v2.replace("$","").replace(",","")))
    self.hsModel.set_sort_func(COL_MONEY, sortmon)
```

This works fine, except that sometimes, when I append a row, I get:

```
stderr      : INFO     Traceback (most recent call last):
stderr      : INFO       File "C:\Users\DrClaud\bumhunter\gui\widgets\replay\ReplayWidget.py", line 141, in sortpot
stderr      : INFO         float(v2.replace("$","").replace(",","")))
stderr      : INFO     AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I did more print outs, and it seems that when I insert a row, one of `model[i1][x]` or `model[i2][x]` for any x will be None. I'm certain I'm not inserting a row with `None` elements in it.. so what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you append a row to a sorted model, GTK+ automatically searches for a proper position for it and thus your sort function is called if it's on that column.  You should either handle `None` specially, or specify initial values in `append()` call, like:

```
model.append (parent, [x, y, z])
```

The latter of course only solves the problem if you can specify something more appropriate than `None`, an empty string, perhaps.

Comment: i am specifying initial values.. how else would you append a row? `model.append(parent)`?

Comment: @Claudiu: I checked PyGTK source code, internally it first appends a blank row, then sets the values you passed.  This is a bug (or maybe a missing feature) in PyGTK, it should use `gtk_tree_store_insert_with_values()` if `row` is specified.  I suggest you file a bug.

Comment: oh hah that explains it.. very interesting. thanks for tracking that down!